# How can we use in-app purchase on dynamic product list in iOS ?

Tags: ios, dynamic, in-app-purchase

I want to buy some of subject's Content using in-app purchase and list of Subject can be manage by admin part and this subject list will be dynamic list so is there any way to purchase dynamic product using in-app purchase in iOS?

Comment: Maybe using some virtual currency to achieve this? Like most games do.

Comment: is this electronic or real world stuff people are buying ?

Comment: user can bye book's content only